# Adding labels to violin plot: Median, upper end and lower end

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, violin-plot

As you can see below my violin chart is lacking labels for the median, the y-axis and the upper boundary, which I would like to add.
[image: Violin chart]

I experimented with

```
plt.text(40,5,'This text ends at point (40,5)',horizontalalignment='right')
```

to place the labels manually, since I couldn't find anything on adding them automatically. However I didn't find a y-value that worked. It only worked for values like (40, 0.2), but the text was below the x-axis and messed up the whole graph.

The data I'm using are wordcounts of reviews in the form of an array:

```
[[ 91]
 [ 48]
 [117]
 ...
 [ 33]
 [ 19]
 [ 29]]
```

My Code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 4))
axes.violinplot(violin,
                   showmeans=False,
                   showmedians=True,
                   vert=False)
axes.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.xscale('log')
axes.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
axes.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

plt.xticks(size = 16)
plt.ylabel('Distribution of reviews',size=14)
plt.xlabel('Number of words per review (logarithmic)',size=14)
axes.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
#plt.text(40,5,'This text ends at point (40,5)',horizontalalignment='right')

fig.tight_layout()    
plt.savefig(figpath+"violin_wordcount.png",dpi=300)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think turning of the y-axis makes it harder to debug this issue, as it is impossible to know what your current range of y-values are.

Comment: Is there no build-in function to add labels to the data points?